# The difference between the minimum and maximum number of games

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, max, min

**Question:** Show the names of all players who have the following:
the difference between the minimum and maximum number of games
this players is greater than 5.

```
select p.name
from player p
join competition c
on c.playerID = p.playerID
where (
(select count(*) from competition
 where count(games) > 1
 group by playerID
) - (
select count(*) from competition
  where count(games) <= 1
  group by playerID
))> 5;
```

I'm kind of lost. I'm not so sure is this the right way, how I should proceed: should I use **count** and find the minimum and maximum number of games and compare with greater than 5 or should I use instead of **count**, **min** and **max** functions. Would be very grateful, if someone can explain me the logic of this.

Tables:

```
player       competition
-------      --------
playerID     playerID
name         games
birthday     date
address      
telefon
```

Comment: share tables data and expected result

Comment: I added the tables, unfortunately I don't have the expected result. @ZaynulAbadinTuhin

Comment: add tables with data and expected result data

Comment: You are counting(games) but there is no games in the Competition Table? is this correct table columns?? Does counting Dates can be assumed as Game count?

Comment: @kik Thank you for providing some schema information. We would prefer the actual `create table` statements, but this is a good start. Now, is the `score` column in the `competition` table the same as "number of games"? For example, if there is a row: `playerID = 1, score = 7, date = ...`, does that mean the player played 7 games on that date? I wouldn't normally think that `score` meant the same thing as "number of games". Maybe this is chess, and the `score` means "number of games won", and what you actually want to compare is the "number of games *won*"?

Comment: I edited the score in the Table, sorry I'm translating the tables from German.
Games means  the number of the game, e.g. game=2, game=15.  @allmhuran

Comment: Expected result data is not given. Only the question and tables. @ZaynulAbadinTuhin

Comment: OK, so let me rephrase your question to see if I have it right: A player has a unique `playerId`. A player can play many games in a competition on a given `date`. The `competition` table has a column called `games`, which stores the number of games played by a given `playerId` on a given `date`.  Find the players where the difference between the minimum number of games played by that player on any date, and the maximum number of games played by that player on any date, is greater than 5. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes exactly  @allmhuran

Comment: @kik Nice. OK, since this looks like a homework/assingment question, I don't want to post the *actual* query. But I will try to give you tips. First of all, you have mentioned `min` and `max` several times... you were on the right track, but you never used them in your query! You will want to use those to get the `min(games)` and the `max(games)` grouped by the `playerId` in the `competition` table. Then you want to compare those two values. Well, to compare the result of aggregate functions, you can't use the `where` clause, right? You have to use the `having` clause.

Comment: Yes, I think I get it now. Thank You! @allmhuran

Comment: @kik Be aware, the answer you have accepted is not entirely correct. It's close. Unless there is a unique constraint on `name` in your schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
P.Name,
MIN(C.Games) MinGame,
MAX(C.Games) MaxGame,
FROM Player P
INNER JOIN Competition C
ON C.PlayerId = P.PlayerId
GROUP BY P.Id, P.Name
HAVING MAX(C.Games) -  MIN(C.Games)  > 5
```

Comment: What if two players have the same name?

Comment: Nope, still not. You can't select `p.name` if you're not grouping by it. You shouldn't post answers you haven't checked.

Comment: How about you check it yourself in a query editor? :D

Comment: Yup sure will check it, Btw thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score -1):

It should be a simple query:

```
With tab1 AS (Select player.name, min(games) mx_game, max(games) min_game,
max(games) - min(games) diff
from player JOIN competition ON player.player_id = competition.id
group by player.player_id, player.name)

Select tab1.name from tab1
WHERE diff >5;
```

I am adding player_id in the group by as player_name could be similar for 2 person.

Comment: I tried it, but I received Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Comment: Nope. Why are you posting answers before running them through a syntax check?